# Is there a way to view the Cassandra custom index

Tags: cassandra

In Cassandra when we create a custom index say 'json_idx'
we have the ability of dropping that index using

```
DROP INDEX json_idx;
```

Is there a way of viewing the content of the index table ? (something like SELECT * from FROM, SHOW or DESC)

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The tool for viewing raw sstables is sstable2json found in `C*/tools/bin`. You can use it as follows (example is inclusive of ks and cf creation / population):

```
cqlsh> CREATE KEYSPACE example WITH replication = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': 1 };
cqlsh> CREATE TABLE example.table1 (id timeuuid, data text, PRIMARY KEY(id));
cqlsh> CREATE INDEX table1_data_idx on example.table1 (data);
cqlsh> INSERT INTO example.table1 (id, data) VALUES (now(), '1');
cqlsh> INSERT INTO example.table1 (id, data) VALUES (now(), '2');
cqlsh> INSERT INTO example.table1 (id, data) VALUES (now(), '3');
cqlsh> INSERT INTO example.table1 (id, data) VALUES (now(), '4');
$ ./bin/nodetool flush
$ ./tools/bin/sstable2json data/data/example/table1-c6163220ede311e4b03c5950fe1805c6/.table1_data_idx/la-1-big-Data.db 
[
  {"key": "1", "cells": [["33a44ed0ede411e4b03c5950fe1805c6","",1430252510243205]]},
  {"key": "2", "cells": [["34e189c0ede411e4b03c5950fe1805c6","",1430252512347428]]},
  {"key": "3", "cells": [["362c5940ede411e4b03c5950fe1805c6","",1430252514515429]]},
  {"key": "4", "cells": [["373c90c0ede411e4b03c5950fe1805c6","",1430252516299193]]}
]
```

The important part is adding the index cf in the path to sstable2json, the path goes something like this:

```
<data_dir>/data/<KS>/<CF-uid>/<secondary-index>/<data-sstable>
```